# react-native-in-app-utils not appropriately entitled

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-in-app-utils to setup in app subscription payments but when I call:

```
var products = [
   'com.xyz.abc',
]; 
InAppUtils.loadProducts(products, (error, products) => {
   //update store here.
});
```

I get:

```
MobileGestaltSupport.m:151: pid 180 (ScriptAgent) does not have sandbox access for and IS NOT appropriately entitled
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have not enabled the `In-App Purchase` capability in your Xcode project.

Go to `Signing & Capabilities`, click `+ Capability`, and then select `In-App Purchase`.